# API force login Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

I'm developing an API for a government agency, they required some conditions like:

Basic Authentication, using a hash:

```
$pass = 'password';
$hash_pass = sha256($pass.date('Y-m-d'));
$full_hash = base_64('username'.':'.$hash_pass);
```

So, they send me a header authorizarion like:

> Basic $full_hash

On my middleware i'm using this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $authorization_code = explode(" ", $request->header('Authorization'));

    $hash = base64_decode($authorization_code[1]);
    $user = explode(":", $hash);

    $data['username'] = $user[0];

    $user_db = User::where('username', $data['username'])->first();

    $data['password'] = $user[1];

    $today = date('Y-m-d');


    $request->headers->set('php-auth-user', $data['username']);
    $request->headers->set('php-auth-pw', $data['password']);

    return $response = auth()->basic('username') ?: $next($request);
}
```

In my database, the password was encrypted with bcrypt.

My question is: There is a way to force login? with my own logic?

If i don't encrypt the password on database, I can compare the $data['password'] with with $user_db->password, using:

```
        if($data['password'] == hash("sha256", $user_db->password.$today, false))
```

Well.. Thank everyone!

Comment: You saved the original password in your database with `bcrypt(password)`, and they're sending you `hash(password)` to authenticate? Am I understanding this correctly? Because if that's the case, there's no way for you to know the original password from the request, which means you can't verify against your bcrypt string

Comment: Hmm... you're right, is that I thinking too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I do the right thing..

But I "solved" this leaving the raw password in database, and comparing like:

```
if($data['password'] == hash("sha256", $user_db->password.$today, false)){

     \Auth::login($user_db);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You definitely shouldn't store a password in plaintext in your database.

You should create an API keys table, where an API key belongs to a user, and use this to authenticate. Then, you can revoke, monitor, etc, usage of each key.

But, do not store a password in plaintext in your database. Ever!